# Sending a personalized Email to each person in a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, email

After searching through this site I came across a macro that almost does exactly what I need. The macro works very well however I would like to tweak a few things but I am not very skilled with VBA.

Here is the link to the macro:

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail8.htm

Here is the code:

```
Sub Send_Row_Or_Rows_2()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim rng As Range
Dim Ash As Worksheet
Dim Cws As Worksheet
Dim Rcount As Long
Dim Rnum As Long
Dim FilterRange As Range
Dim FieldNum As Integer

On Error GoTo cleanup
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

'Set filter sheet, you can also use Sheets("MySheet")
Set Ash = ActiveSheet

'Set filter range and filter column (column with e-mail addresses)
Set FilterRange = Ash.Range("A1:H" & Ash.Rows.Count)
FieldNum = 2    'Filter column = B because the filter range start in column A

'Add a worksheet for the unique list and copy the unique list in A1
Set Cws = Worksheets.Add
FilterRange.Columns(FieldNum).AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CopyToRange:=Cws.Range("A1"), _
        CriteriaRange:="", Unique:=True

'Count of the unique values + the header cell
Rcount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cws.Columns(1))

'If there are unique values start the loop
If Rcount >= 2 Then
    For Rnum = 2 To Rcount

        'Filter the FilterRange on the FieldNum column
        FilterRange.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, _
                               Criteria1:=Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value

        'If the unique value is a mail addres create a mail
        If Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then

            With Ash.AutoFilter.Range
                On Error Resume Next
                Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                On Error GoTo 0
            End With

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .to = Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value
                .Subject = "Test mail"
                .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
                .Display  'Or use Send
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If

        'Close AutoFilter
        Ash.AutoFilterMode = False

    Next Rnum
End If

cleanup:
Set OutApp = Nothing
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Cws.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

Here is the function also included in the macro:

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile
Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

My goal is to send out emails to every email address in my worksheet, CCing the second email address that is included in the row of data, and including the data from the row in the body of the email.

So the data in my excel worksheet looks like this (Columns A-G):

```
main-email@abc.com  -  second-email@abc.com  -  data1  -  data2  -  data3  -  data4  -  data5
```

Column A is the main email, Column B is the email that will be CC'd, and Columns C-G will be the data that gets included in the body of the email.

I am currently using the code from Example 2 in the link above. The code autofilters my data for every unique email address so it does not send multiple emails to the same address which is amazing. One issue is that the macro includes the entire row of data (Columns A-G) in the body of the email. I would like it to only show columns C-G.

```
            With Ash.AutoFilter.Range
                On Error Resume Next
                Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                On Error GoTo 0
            End With
```

Would adding a .Offset here allow the macro to only take the data from columns C-G?

The other issue is that the macro does not include a way to CC the second email address that is included in each row of data. Can someone help me achieve this?

Also would it be possible to have the macro prepare one email at a time instead of sending them all at once? My worksheet has about 300 unique email addresses and I would like to check them and then send them manually one at a time. Is there a way to have it prepare the email and continue onto the next one as soon as I click send?

Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**: I refactored the code to clean it up a bit.  [Here is my Test Stub](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rga3ydq94dhzxiz/EMD023%20-%20Create%20Emails.xlsm?dl=0).  It should work flawlessly.

Use this with the `RangetoHTML. It will iterate through  your list and create the emails. I left some of the options in there in case you would like to add them later.  By commenting out`.Send` the emails will not be sent.  You will be able to review them from the **Draft Folder**  in Outlook.

Option Explicit

```
Sub CreateEmails()
    Dim HTMLBody As String
    Dim lastRow As Long, x As Long
    Dim DataRange As Range
    Dim Subject As String

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        lastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For x = 2 To lastRow
            If Not .Rows(x).Hidden Then
                Set DataRange = .Range(.Cells(x, 3), .Cells(x, 7))

                HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(DataRange)

                Subject = "Yadda Yadda"

                SendEmail .Cells(x, 1), .Cells(x, 2), Subject, HTMLBody
            End If
        Next

    End With



End Sub

Sub SendEmail(addressTo As String, addressCC As String, Subject As String, HTMLBody As String)
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    On Error Resume Next

    With OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        .To = addressTo
        .CC = addressCC
        'OutMail.BCC = ""

        .Subject = Subject
        .HTMLBody = HTMLBody

        .Save

    End With

    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
    ' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
    ' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile
    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Mail merge does not have the option to CC

Comment: I got an error at the OutMail.Body = RangetoHTML() line.

Comment: I have a mismatch error:   lastrow = range("A" & Rows.Count).End(x1Up)

Comment: Thanks again for your help. It did run without any errors but I cant seem to find the emails anywhere. They are not appearing in the outbox.

Comment: Hmm. I do not have anything in my drafts. I wonder if I have it set up correctly. I have your code and the RangetoHTML function pasted into one module.

Comment: Hi Thomas. Could you paste your code so I can try it out with my Excel? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Thomas. This works very well however my worksheet has multiple lines of data. Your code will send multiple emails to the same person whereas the code i posted will autofilter and only send 1 email. Is there a way to edit this in?

Comment: Run-time error '438'
Object doesn't support this property or method

'If Not .Row(x).Hidden Then'

Comment: @emd023 sorry I was rushing.  My answer is updated.  It should be `Rows` not `Row`

Comment: There are still multiple emails being created for emails that have multiple rows of data. Only 1 email will needs to be created for each unique address and it should include each row of data in the body.

Thank you for helping!!

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with the range. You found the right part to alter. What you're looking for is `Intersect`.

```
 With Ash.AutoFilter.Range
     On Error Resume Next
     Set rng = Intersect(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), Ash.Range("C:G"))
     On Error GoTo 0
 End With
```

Regarding pausing the loop... Without researching the API, it appears he's using `With OutMail` `.Display` to send the email. You may wish to try putting in a message box or something before that line.

For the CC, the "OutMail" object has a method for CCs, just like it has one for Tos. I added in a line below for the CC, assuming they're stored in the 2nd column.

```
With OutMail
    .to = Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value
    .CC = Cws.Cells(Rnum, 2).Value
    .Subject = "Test mail"
    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
    .Display  'Or use Send
End With
```

Comment: Would you be able to help me out with my CC issue?

Comment: Ah, yes. In your `With OutMail` section, you have the line `.to = Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value`. Try adding a line: `.CC = Cws.Cells(Rnum, 2).Value`.

Comment: I added the CC bit to my answer.

Comment: I ran a test, and the `.CC` method works. I think what is happening is that it's copying over just the one column for the address list, so the `Cws` sheet range only has one column, which is the CC column, confusingly. Later, it pulls the body text from the original `Ash` sheet range. That's just asking for mismatches. To solve, I'd probably scrap the new sheet and just go off the `Ash` sheet's visible filtered cells. That way, you'll have everything there to reference. Right now, it's CCing blanks. I can help rewrite, but not until this evening.

Comment: Hi JMcD. Were you able to rewrite the code to pull from the Ash sheet range?